# How to extends Class using Activity instead of ListActivity

Tags: android, android-listview

In my program one of the java **class extends ListActivity** but in place of extending ListActivity i am ***trying to extend simple Activity***, but getting **few errors** like:

1. The method **setListAdapter(ListAdapter) is undefined** for the type PlayListActivity
2. The method **getListView() is undefined** for the type PlayListActivity

**code**:

```
public class PlayListActivity extends Activity {
// Songs list
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_playlist);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();
    // get all songs from sdcard
    this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();

    // looping through playlist
    for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsListData.add(song);
    }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
            R.layout.activity_playlist_item, new String[] { "songTitle" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.songTitle });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();
    // listening to single listitem click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        }
    });
}
```

**activity_playlist_item.xml;**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="sans" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_playlist.xml;**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

       <ListView 
         android:id="@android:id/list" 
         android:layout_height="match_parent" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am placing ***solution for learners*** [like: me], please see below:

```
// declare listview globally
ListView lv ;
// reference to ListView
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
// set list adapter to ListView
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and also change

```
<ListView 
         android:id="@+id/list" .... />
```

**Thanks** to @Raghunandan & @SimplePlan for the ***guidance*** !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The method setListAdapter(ListAdapter) is undefined for the type
>   PlayListActivity

`setListAdapter` is method of `ListActivity`.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#setListAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#setListAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29)

> The method getListView() is undefined for the type PlayListActivity

`getListView()` is method of `ListActivity`.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListView%28%29)

Instead of

```
setListAdapter(adapter);

// selecting single ListView item
ListView lv = getListView();
```

Change to

```
 ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
 lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Change to

```
 <ListView 
     android:id="@+idlist"
```

Comment: but still getting: The method setListAdapter(ListAdapter) is undefined for the type PlayListActivity

Comment: @Sophie remove that piece of code form your activtiy

Comment: please check my edited code below: I am placing solution for learners [like: me] & let me am i getting it correctly ?

Answer (score 3):

If you extends `ListActivity` then defined your `ListView` in XML like below and implement `getListView()` method of `ListActivity`.

```
 <ListView 
     android:id="@android:id/list" 
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

and if you extend `Activity` then defined your `ListView` in XML like below and no need to implement `getListView()` for this.

```
<ListView 
     android:id="@+id/list" 
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

and also you initialized your `ListView` like

```
 ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
 lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: i ticked your solution as useful